# Can we expdp using JOINS in QUERY clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I have a task to export data from database using data pump. I have successfully exported database using subquery in QUERY clause. But I want to know can we expdp using joins in QUERY clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QUERY` parameter is used to restrict data in the export job. If you want to export number of rows that are exist in another table then you can use subquery in `QUERY` parameter.

If you want to join two tables and export you can create table by joining two tables. As shown below.

```
SQL> create table export_tbl as select e.first_name FN, d.department_name DN from employees e join departments d on(e.department_id=d.department_id);

Table created.
```

Then can export it.

```
[oracle@testsrv Desktop]$ expdp hr/hr directory=user_dir dumpfile=export.dmp tables=export_tbl logfile=export.log
```

Alternatively,  you can create a view by joining tables and export views(`INCLUDE=VIEWS`). You have to filter views during import.